# Lambda function to simplify unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have an Sport class defined as:

```
Sport:
 - name
 - other fields
```

I have a test where I want to verify that adding the sport 'rugby' is contained in the list of sport_objects.

Currently, the test is brittle, checking the name of the object at the index I know it's at:

```
self.assertEquals('rugby', sports_objects[3].name)
```

I'd like to change this to self.assertIn() so the test isn't as brittle and won't be affected if the index changes (since I don't care about the order here).

Is there a way to change this (using a lambda function?) without relying on the index?

**Edit:**

Both answers given work great.  I have multiple assert statements, so my final solution is:

```
sports_names = [i.name for i in sports_objects]
self.assertIn('rugby', sports_names)
self.assertIn('baseball', sports_names)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.assertIn('rugby', [sport_object.name for sport_object in sports_objects])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always do:

```
self.assertIn('rugby', (x.name for x in sports_objects))
```

or something like

```
import operator
op = operator.attrgetter("name")
self.assertIn('rugby', map(op, sport_objects))
```